# Setting up master/slave databases on same server?

Tags: mysql, database-replication, amazon-rds, master-slave

I'm looking to have a master and slave DB on the same server, both in an Amazon RDS instance.  Is this possible?  I'm using MySQL Workbench to access it and am a little confused with the instructions I have seen so far.

Comment: Why do you want master and slaves on the same server? Surely the point of replication is if one database server fails, there’s another your application can use? Or are you wanting a slave for reading and your master for writing or something?

Comment: Right the goal is to have slave to read and master to write.

Answer (score 1):

"On the same server" is not possible with Amazon RDS  for MySQL, because RDS is a *managed* service.  Amazon provides, configures, and has exclusive access to the actual server where an RDS instance is running... you, the user, do not have direct (shell) access to that machine, so you can't do the kind of customization of configuration that running a master and slave on the same server would require.

Answer (score 0):

Other being not possibile since RDS is a managed MySQL (you don't have SSH access or SUPER privileges) it would be also not that useful:

You make a slave replica for scaling out or for backup/failover, on the same machine it doens't make sense